# Unity3D Porque minha camera está rotacionando de maneira brusca, personagem até fica piscando

Tags: c#, unity3d, jogos, unity-5

Fiz uma camera para meu jogo em terceira pessoa, mas na hora dela rotacionar junto ao player, o player as vezes até fica desaparecendo, parece até que o fps abaixa (mas é só impressão). Já fiz o teste de rotacionar ela apenas no eixo X e ela funcionou, mas quando envolve X e Y ela tem esse bug. Este é meu código, há alguma maneira de suavizar esta camera?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class cameraLook : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float rotationSpeed = 1;
    float mouseX, mouseY;

    public float zoomMax = 60f;
    public float zoomMin = 40f;
    public float zoomSpeed = 0.1f;
  
    public Transform cam, player;
    
    
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {

        CamControl();

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Zoom();
    }


    void Zoom()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
        {
            Camera.main.fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(Camera.main.fieldOfView, zoomMin, zoomSpeed);
        }
        else
        {
            Camera.main.fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(Camera.main.fieldOfView, zoomMax, zoomSpeed);
        }
    }

    void CamControl()
    {
        mouseX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotationSpeed;
        mouseY -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * rotationSpeed; //negativo pois queremos inverter
        mouseY = Mathf.Clamp(mouseY, -35, 35); //limitar campo de visao olhar pra cima e baixo

        transform.LookAt(cam); //foca no alvo

        //rotação do jogador
        cam.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(mouseY, mouseX, 0);
        player.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, mouseX, 0);
    }

}
```

Comment: não seria o caso de diminuir o "rotationSpeed"?

Answer (score 0):

Postagem antiga, mas pra quem tem duvida, na rotação do player, em vez de usar quaternion, use Rotate, para dar uma suavizada,
ficaria: Player.Rotate(0,MouseX,0);
se ainda ficar estranho cria uma outra váriavel para armazenar o Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
mas sem o "+=".
fica: MouseXPlayer = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).